# Why can I not create a HashMap with 'long' types in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

Any reason that the following is not allowed?

```
HashMap<long, long> x = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Take a look at autoboxing in Java.

Comment: Here's [some documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you're using primitives rewrite to `HashMap<Long,Long> x = new HashMap<>()`

Comment: Yes, this is one of the differences between C# and Java. In Java, you cannot use primitive types for generic type arguments.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, types with generic type parameters, such as HashMap, only accept types that inherit from Object. long does not inherit from Object, so you can't use it with HashMap. You can however use Long, which is a boxed version of long.

Answer (score 5):

Using standard collections for primitive types like long is not really effective

If you need to minimize memory footprint and get better performance you should consider 3rd-party collection libraries like [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)